# Login using NFS and LDAP only after about 2 minutes possible

Tags: 13.04, nfs, ldap

Setup:
NFS&LDAP Server Ubuntu 10.04
Client Ubuntu 13.04

After starting the client login is only possible after about 2 minutes. Problem seems missing home (mounted via NFS v4).

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

We had a NFSv3 entry in /etc/fstab and apparently this caused the problem.